# Parsing Multiple files argparse

Tags: python, parsing, argparse

I am having trouble figuring out how to parse multiple files through my program. As of right now I can parse a singular file and populate my dictionary without any problems. However I'm struggling to parse multiple files through my script. When including the several files for parsing using a wildcard (*.txt), my program acts as only one file is being parsed (assuming its either the first or the last file apart of this group). How can I use my program to iterate over a list of files instead of just a single file.

The code below shows my parsing arguments as well as how pass the file into the `__init__`

```
def __init__(self, file):
     self.file = file

def main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", dest="input_file", required = True,
                    help="The binary file to be writen to flash")
    parser.add_argument('file', type=argparse.FileType('wb'), nargs='*')

    args = parser.parse_args(argv)

    fault_finder = FaultList(args.input_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

I assume I need to iterate over a list of the parsed files but I am unsure how.

Comment: Your parser expects ONE input filename, the string following '-f', and multiple files names to write to (the '*' positional).  Because of the `FileType` specification, it creates and opens those output files.  But since you don't use `args.file`  you aren't doing anything with those output files.  We have no idea what `FaultList` does with the one input file name that you pass it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `glob` in conjunction with `argparse` to obtain a list of all the files matching the wildcards.

```
import argparse  
from glob import glob  

def main(file_names):  
    print file_names  

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()  
    parser.add_argument("file_names", nargs='*') 
    #nargs='*' to combine all positional arguments into a single list 

    args = parser.parse_args()  
    file_names = []

    # use glob to find files matching wildcards
    #if a string does not contain a wildcard, glob will return it as is.
    for arg in args.file_names:  
        file_names += glob(arg)  

main(file_names)
```